# Complex number equation $(\frac{(\sqrt3 + i)}{1-i})^{25}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to calculate real, imaginary, modulus and Arg of the following

> $(\frac{(\sqrt3 + i)}{1-i})^{25}$

I stucked on the following part

> $(\frac{(\sqrt3 + i)(1+i)}{2})^{25} = (\frac{(\sqrt 3-1) + i(\sqrt 3 + 1)}{2})^{25}$

Could you please provide any idea how can I solve it ?

Comment: Convert both of the numbers to polar form $re^{i\theta}$

Comment: Note that $\sin \frac{5π}{12}=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2\sqrt 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have expanded $(\sqrt 3+i)(1+i)$ as you did. It's much easier if you calculate $(\sqrt 3+i)^{25}$ and $(1+i)^{25}$ separately, because both can be expressed as $re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ a nice multiple of $\pi$. Drawing a picture might help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt3 + i = 2(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i) = 2(cos(\frac{\pi}{6}) + sin(\frac{\pi}{6})i)$$
applying euler identity,
$$\sqrt3 + i = 2e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}$$
Similarly
$$1 - i = \sqrt2(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i) = \sqrt2(cos(-\frac{\pi}{4}) + sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})i) = \sqrt2 e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}$$

$$(\frac{\sqrt3 + i}{1 - i})^{25} = (\frac{2e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}}{\sqrt2 e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}i}})^{25} = (\sqrt{2}e^{(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{4})i})^{25} = 2^{12}\sqrt{2}e^{25\times\frac{5\pi}{12}i} = 4096\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{125\pi}{12}i}$$
$\frac{5\pi}{12}$ is the principal value for $\frac{125\pi}{12}$. So,
$$(\frac{\sqrt3 + i}{1 - i})^{25} = 4096\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{5\pi}{12}i} = 4096\sqrt{2}(cos(\frac{5\pi}{12})+sin(\frac{5\pi}{12})i)$$
$Re(z) =4096\sqrt{2}\times cos(\frac{5\pi}{12})$
$Im(z) =4096\sqrt{2}\times sin(\frac{5\pi}{12})$
$|z| = 4096\sqrt{2}$
$Arg(z) = \frac{5\pi}{12}$